# Modal dialog. - Confusing

Tags: magnific-popup

I am trying to open a simple modal dialog and I have been struggling to do this. Can

any one please help? This is the HTML code(please remove pre). This simply doesnot work.

Can any one please tell **strong text**me why? I have not been getting the kind of output that I really 
need.

Any one help me.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>


    <a class="popup-modal" href="#test-modal">Open modal</a>

<div id="test-modal" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
    <h1>Modal dialog</h1>
    <p>You won't be able to dismiss this by usual means (escape or
        click button), but you can close it programatically based on
        user choices or actions.</p>
    <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a></p>
</div>


    <script>

        $(function () {
            $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
                type: 'inline',
                preloader: false,
                focus: '#username',
                modal: true
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Load jquery before the magnific-popup plugin, it relies on jquery (I've never used it but I'm assuming so seeeing as it is pre-appended withfixed 'jquery')

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Jquery loaded first here... -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <!-- Plugins after... -->
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
```